# Gnome-tweak-tool -- cannot read Typing Options due to ellipsized text

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I would like to use the gnome-tweak tool to remap some of my modifier keys (alt/win/meta/super or how they're all called..)

My problem is that I can't really read what the options in the drop down menu are doing (see picture, there is no tooltip which would tell me what is behind those dots). It would be /very/ helpful if someone could help me out some way (e.g. a screenshot of your system if you can read them, some official list or a tip how I could make them readable)

[image]

EDIT: My gnome version is 3.14.1, OS debian jessie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=711137) and it's already fixed in git.
If you don't want to wait until `3.18` will be available in debian repos you have two options:

- the quick and dirty hack:
  close tweak-tool and as root, open `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_xkb.py`

  look for a line like

  ```
     renderer.props.max_width_chars = 30
  ```

  and change the width as per your taste, e.g.

  ```
     renderer.props.max_width_chars = 100
  ```

  save changes then restart tweak-tool.
- patch the above mentioned file using the diff from [here](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-tweak-tool/commit/?id=0fa44ef); result:

  [image]

Comment: Offtopic: Which theme is that?

Comment: @Muru - that is the official _Dark_ variant of the vanilla _Adwaita_ theme (aka _Adwaita Dark_ which should be available on any gnome3 setup). The more recent your DE/gtk3 apps, the better the dark variant is supported (e.g. I'm currently using Firefox 39 built against gtk3 and it perfectly integrates with the DE/rest of the apps).

Comment: ah, the one you get with Dark mode slider? I'd stopped trying it a few versions ago, maybe I should give it another chance.